# How to pass an onKeyDown event as a prop to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have an input with an onChange attribute and an onKeyDown attribute. The onChange attribute receives a value of `{(e) => props.change(e)}` and in the parent component I assign the change prop to a handleChange function. I want to do the same thing with my onKeyDown attribute, however I face two issues:

When I use `{(e) => props.key(e)}`, Chrome Devtools says that key is not a prop. When I try passing {key} instead of (props) to the child component, Chrome Devtools says that key is not a function.

I'm trying to pass the prop so that I can consume the key code value in the parent component and execute some logic.

I've also tested to make sure the function is working within Home.js. If someone could give a solution and an explanation as to why this happens I would be appreciative.

Here is an example of my code:

```
/ App.js

export default function App() {
const key = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 8) {
   ...
  }
}

const change = (e) => {
  return ...
}

return
<Home
  key={key}
  change={change}
/>
}

/ Home.js
export default function Home(props) {
return 
<input
  onChange={(e) => props.change(e)}
  onKeyDown={(e) => props.key(e)}
/>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`key` is a special prop in React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html) and gets special treatment:

> […] there are two special props (`ref` and `key`) which are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component.

So it should work if you change the name of the prop:

#### App.js

```jsx
export default function App() {
// …
return
<Home
  myKey={key}
  change={change}
/>
}
```

#### Home.js

```jsx
export default function Home(props) {
return 
<input
  onChange={(e) => props.change(e)}
  onKeyDown={(e) => props.myKey(e)}
/>
}
```